# Ссылка которая обходит встроенный браузер

Tags: google-chrome, url, safari

Как для IOS сформировать ссылку которая будет открываться только в Safari?

Если для android всё довольно просто, то как подобное сделать для Safari?

```
<a href="googlechrome://navigate?url=https://yandex.ru/">Магические ссылки</a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kHFjM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `target="_blank"` (откроет ссылку в новом окне браузера). Для каждой OS браузер свой: для iOS - Safari, для Android - Chrome.